# Synchronise scrolling NSTableView with a NSOutlineView in swift - Live scroll notifications from NSScrollView

Tags: cocoa, notifications, nsscrollview, macos-mojave

Started with NSClipview notifications and didn't work out. No marriage here. Then I saw this 'didLiveScrollNotification' in the docs, this [Swift NSScrollView better NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification observing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465033/swift-nsscrollview-better-nsviewboundsdidchangenotification-observing), and http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSScrollView.

But I can't get it working to receive any notification, i am more confused then what I did read there.
What is the up to date way for macos > 10.12 ( swift 4.2 xcode 9 or 10 ) to get two or more tableviews in sync with scrolling?

Any pointers or sample or tutorial about this?

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar with great success, though not with an NSTableView as the content. Try observing NSView.boundsDidChangeNotification on the ScrollView's content view. You'll also need to enable them with:

```
scrollView.contentView.postsBoundsChangedNotifications = true
```

Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, you may also need to know when the scroll view itself is resized. I also do this with NSView.frameDidChangeNotification on the scrollview.

```
    scrollView.postsFrameChangedNotifications = true
```

The second link you posted looks most or less exactly right to me, but will need to be translated to Swift.

Comment: Thank you. It looks i have enough points to react and thank you.